# replace span tag with several links by a click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

when i click this tag the popup opens up

```
<span class="en_US tk-museo-sans locale-select-lable">United States</span>
```

when i click the link inside the pop up the pop up closes

```
<span class="selectorCountries locale-link">united states</span>
<span class="selectorCountries marginSecondCountry locale-link">canada</span>
<span class="selectorCountries marginCanadaFrench locale-link">canada(french)</span>
```

the problem is when i click the link inside the pop up this tag

```
<span class="en_US tk-museo-sans locale-select-lable">United States</span>
```

should be replaced by the country name...

the problem is with jquery code...

http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/145/

can u tell me how to fix it...

i am providing my latest js code

```
    // locale selector actions
    $('#region-picker').click(function(){
            if ($("#locale-select").is(":visible")) return closeSelector('slide');


        var foot_height = $('#footer').innerHeight();
        var foot_height_css = foot_height-1;
        var select_position = '-=' + (Number(700)+18);
        console.log("hallo"+select_position);
        var $selector = $('#locale-select');
        $('#locale_pop').fadeOut();
        $selector.css({top:foot_height_css});
        $selector.fadeIn(function(){
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).animate({top:select_position}, 1000);
            });
    });
    $('#select-tab').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        closeSelector('slide');
        });
    // don't hide when clicked within the box
    $('#locale-select').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){ 
        if ($('#locale-select').hasClass('open')) {
            closeSelector('disappear');
        }
    });

    $('.locale-link').click(function(){
        if ($("#locale-select").is(":visible")) return closeSelector('slide');
       /*         
       // var desired_locale = $(this).attr('rel');
       // createCookie('desired-locale',desired_locale,360);
       // createCookie('buy_flow_locale',desired_locale,360);
        //closeSelector('disappear');
        */
    })

    $('#locale_pop a.close').click(function(){
        var show_blip_count = readCookie('show_blip_count');
        if (!show_blip_count) {
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        else if (show_blip_count < 3 ) {
            eraseCookie('show_blip_count');
            createCookie('show_blip_count',3,360);
        }
        $('#locale_pop').slideUp();
        return false;
    });

function closeSelector(hide_type){
var foot_height = $('#footer').innerHeight();
var select_position = '+=' + (Number(400)+20);
if (hide_type == 'slide') {
$('#locale-select').animate({top:select_position}, 1000, function(){
$(this).removeClass('open');
$(this).fadeOut()
});
}
else if (hide_type == 'disappear'){
$('#locale-select').fadeOut('fast');
$('#locale-select').removeClass('open');
}
}
```

​

Comment: did you mean to do this? $(document).click(function(){ 
        if ($('#locale-select').hasClass('open')) {
            closeSelector('disappear');
        }
    });
you want a click  event handler on the Window.Document?

Comment: @awright18: thanks for your reply....http://www.teslamotors.com/ in this link when they click different countries in the link the flag image changes corresponding to different countries....but here i wanted to replace with different countries name...

Comment: I don't see anywhere to choose a conuntry

Comment: when u scroll down to the bottom of the page http://www.teslamotors.com/

Comment: check this fiddle is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/5dedF/

Comment: @rajeshkakawat: thanks for your reply can you tell me what you add it.

Comment: I have added js code at bootom for replacing text

Comment: @rajesh: thnks for your reply if i wanted to replace with text with different countries flags...what should i do...

Comment: our flag is coming but path to your flag image is incorrect check it

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 $('.locale-link').click(function(){
        $("#region-picker:first-child").text(this.text());
        if ($("#locale-select").is(":visible")) return closeSelector('slide');
   })
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6QXGG/146/embedded/result/ here u can see the red button... when i click the link with the country name...i wanted it to get replaced with corresponding country names...after commenting i out if i click the link the popup does not closes out...